# Unexpected breakpoint trying to print C string from struct

Tags: c

So I am having two problems with this piece of code. The first problem when I'm following break points through it and I'm trying to copy the array to the struct fields, it is saying `Error reading character string`. And the second problem I am having is with the output "printMovieInfo function it is not printing out my list and it is causing an "unexpected breakpoint"

```
        #include<stdio.h>
        #include<string.h>
        #include<stdlib.h>
        #pragma warning(disable : 4996)
        #pragma warning(disable : 6387)
    
    typedef struct {
        char* g;
        char* t;
    }MovieInfo;
    
    #define kTenItemsEntered 10
    #define kCharacterString 30 
    
    //prototypes
    void eliminateEndOfLine(char* buffer); 
    void getMovieInfo(MovieInfo* ptr, char title[], char genre[]); 
    void printMovieInfo(MovieInfo list[]); 
    
    int main() {
    
        MovieInfo newMovieInfo[kTenItemsEntered]; 
        char title[kCharacterString]; 
        char genre[kCharacterString];
    
        printf("Enter 10 Title of Movie and 10 Genres\n"); 
    
        for (int i = 1; i <= kTenItemsEntered; i++) {
    
            printf("%d:\n", i); 
    
            printf("Title: ");
            fgets(title, kCharacterString,stdin); 
            eliminateEndOfLine(title); 
    
            printf("Genre: "); 
            fgets(genre, kCharacterString, stdin); 
            eliminateEndOfLine(genre); 
    
            getMovieInfo(newMovieInfo, title, genre); 
        }
    
        printMovieInfo(newMovieInfo); 
        return 0; 
    }
    
   void getMovieInfo(MovieInfo* ptr, char title[], char genre[]) {
    
    ptr->t = (char*)malloc(strlen(title) + 1);
    if (ptr->t == NULL) {
        printf("Error allocating the title in the struct\n");
    }

    ptr->g = (char*)malloc(strlen(genre) + 1);
    if (ptr->g == NULL) {
        printf("Error allocating the genre in the struct\n");
    }

    strcpy(ptr->t, title);
    strcpy(ptr->g, genre);
}
    
void printMovieInfo(MovieInfo list[]) {
    printf("%-35s %-35s\n", "Title", "Genre");
    for (int i = 0; i < kTenItemsEntered; i++) {
        printf("%-35s %-35s\n", list[i].t, list[i].g);
    }
}
    
    //This is the end of new line function from examples
    void eliminateEndOfLine(char* buffer)
    {
        char* target = strchr(buffer, '\n');
        if (target != NULL)
        {
            *target = '\0';
        }
    }
```

[image: This photo show what the values are when the unexpected breakpoint appears in the printMovieInfo function]

Output

[image: Things entered]

[image: The output should print here]

The output does not print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're actually compiling in C++, otherwise this wouldn't compile as you need to use `struct MovieInfo`, not `MovieInfo` in C. You can fix that by doing:

```
typedef struct MovieInfo {
    char* g;
    char* t;
} MovieInfo;
```

In `main` your `newMovieInfo` is an array of `MovieInfo` structs. When you call `getMovieInfo(newMovieInfo, title, genre);`, you're actually passing a pointer to the first element of the array to the function (the array 'decays' into a pointer to the first element). What you should do instead is pass a pointer to the element you actually want to fill in. Array indices start at 0, not 1, so you need to fix your loop as well:

```
// previously: for (int i = 1; i <= kTenItemsEntered; i++) {
for (int i = 0; i < kTenItemsEntered; i++) {
    ...
    // previously: getMovieInfo(newMovieInfo, title, genre);
    getMovieInfo(&newMovieInfo[i], title, genre); 
}
```

Then in `getMovieInfo`, since you already have a valid pointer to the struct, you don't need to allocate space for a new one:

```
void getMovieInfo(MovieInfo* ptr, char title[], char genre[]) {
    // removed:
    // ptr = (MovieInfo*)malloc(sizeof(MovieInfo));
    // if (ptr == NULL) {
    //     printf("Error allocating the struct\n");
    // }
    ptr->t = (char*)malloc(strlen(title) + 1);
    if (ptr->t == NULL) {
        printf("Error allocating the title in the struct\n");
    }

    ptr->g = (char*)malloc(strlen(genre) + 1);
    if (ptr->g == NULL) {
        printf("Error allocating the genre in the struct\n");
    }

    strcpy(ptr->t, title);
    strcpy(ptr->g, genre); 
}
```

Finally in `printMovieInfo`, your current code is printing the first element's data multiple times. You can fix that by indexing into the array to get the element you want:

```
void printMovieInfo(MovieInfo list[]) {
    printf("%-35s %-35s\n", "Title", "Genre"); 
    for (int i = 0; i < kTenItemsEntered; i++) {
        // previously: printf("%-35s %-35s\n",list->t,list->g);
        printf("%-35s %-35s\n",list[i].t,list[i].g);
    }
}
```

Comment: With all of the changes you made to my code. The unexpected breakpoint is still coming up on the printf(""%-35s %-35s\n",list[i].t,list[i].g); line

Comment: @ErikHolmes did you make all of the changes? You seemed to have edited your original question with *some* of my changes (you shouldn't do that though as it means existing answers no longer apply), but not all of them. You didn't make the changes I made in your `main` function.

Comment: I have completed all the changes you made even  the ones in the main function now. This line is not printing anything. printf(""%-35s %-35s\n",list[i].t,list[i].g); This line right here seems to be the issue and I don't know why

Comment: It still saying down in the local variables that there is an Error reading character string

Comment: @ErikHolmes I copied the code you have in your question, made the fix in `main`, and [it works fine for me](https://ideone.com/epVHxh) (scroll down to see input/output)

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call `getMovieInfo`, you're storing the data in a local pointer to allocated memory.  That pointer gets lost when the function returns, so `newMovieInfo` is never populated with anything.

The pointer being passed to the function points to an already existing instance of `MovieInfo`, so there's no need to allocate memory for it (though you still need to allocate memory for the strings).

Even after this fix, you're only ever updating the first element of the `newMovieInfo`.  You need to pass a pointer to the array element in question when you call `getMovieInfo`:

```
getMovieInfo(newMovieInfo + i - 1, title, genre);
```

Note the -1 here because you're looping from 1 to `kTenItemsEntered` and array indices in C start at 0.  If you changed the loop to go from 0 to `kTenItemsEntered-1`, you can remove the -1 from the line above.

Your printing function is also only printing the first element of the array, so change the line in the loop body to:

```
printf("%-35s %-35s\n",list[i].t,list[i].g);
```